# Controller "Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Controller\PostController::homeAction" for URI news is not callable

Tags: symfony

I am using SonataNewsBundle with symfony 2.5.

If I run .. /web/news/
showing error

Controller "Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\Controller\PostController::homeAction" for URI news is not callable.

please help anyone

Comment: Can you post the output of `php app/console container:debug`? First remove your custom service to avoid the container from throwing more errors. My first guest is that the service no longer exists or the name has changed.

Answer (score 0):

My container:debug is below - a portion of news bundle

```
 sonata.news.block.breadcrumb_archive                                 container Sonata\NewsBundle\Block\Breadcrumb\NewsArchiveBreadcrumbBlockService                       
 sonata.news.block.breadcrumb_post                                    container Sonata\NewsBundle\Block\Breadcrumb\NewsPostBreadcrumbBlockService                          
 sonata.news.block.recent_comments                                    container Sonata\NewsBundle\Block\RecentCommentsBlockService                                         
 sonata.news.block.recent_posts                                       container Sonata\NewsBundle\Block\RecentPostsBlockService                                            
 sonata.news.blog                                                     container Sonata\NewsBundle\Model\Blog                                                               
 sonata.news.form.comment.status_type                                 container Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\StatusType                                                     
 sonata.news.form.type.comment                                        container Sonata\NewsBundle\Form\Type\CommentType                                                    
 sonata.news.hash.generator                                           container Sonata\NewsBundle\Util\HashGenerator                                                       
 sonata.news.mailer                                                   container Sonata\NewsBundle\Mailer\Mailer                                                            
 sonata.news.manager.comment                                          container Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\CommentManager                                                    
 sonata.news.manager.post                                             container Sonata\NewsBundle\Entity\PostManager                                                       
 sonata.news.permalink.collection                                     container Sonata\NewsBundle\Permalink\CollectionPermalink                                            
 sonata.news.permalink.date                                           container Sonata\NewsBundle\Permalink\DatePermalink                                                  
 sonata.news.permalink.generator                                      n/a       alias for "sonata.news.permalink.date"                                                     
 sonata.news.serializer.handler.post                                  container Sonata\NewsBundle\Serializer\PostSerializerHandler                                         
 sonata.news.status.comment                                           container Sonata\NewsBundle\Status\CommentStatusRenderer
```